# Powerpoint VBA setting ComandButton shape to Hidden

Tags: vba, powerpoint, shapes

I've got a macro that searches through all the shapes in a slide and hides the shapes that match certain names. My shapes collection includes a mixture of standard shapes and CommandButtons.

The Command Buttons are having their "Visible" property set to "False" in the properties window, and they aren't visible in the powerpoint edit screen, but they remain visible in the Slide Show view. This issue doesn't occur when I bypass the shape variable (sh.Visible) and refer to the command button directly (startB.Visible). See below:

```
For Each sh In ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes
    If sh.Name = "startB" Then
        sh.Visible = False
    End If
Next
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming it's because the shape is just a component of the Command Button. As a work around, I've got this, though I'm not 100% confident in why this happens:

```
If sh.Name = "startB" Then
    sh.OLEFormat.Object.Visible = False
End If
```

Which works fine. I'm a bit lost here because I'm used to Excel where I could refer directly to things as OLEObject.Object, but even though you are still referring to OLEObjects, OLEFormat seems a little different. Just having some issues wrapping my head around it.

Comment: And Intellisense doesn't offer any help.  But for the most part, if you look at the properties and methods of the equivalent command button on a VBA form, they'll apply to the OLEformat.Object of a command button on a slide. And that'll provide Intellisense help.

Answer (score 0):

When looping through shapes, form control name needs to be checked against the object. I added a first If statement to check the type of shape. Then, the second If will access OLEFormat Object Name.

```
If sh.Type = msoOLEControlObject Then
    If sh.OLEFormat.Object.Name = "startB" Then
        sh.Visible = False        
    End If
End If
```

Comment: This provides the same result, in that the properties menu and the edit view show the button as hidden (and if I escape the Slide Show then resume it from the same slide, it's also hidden), but it is not hidden in the Slide Show view

Comment: What happens if you change the code to `sh.Visible = Not sh.Visible`